# ESLint no-undef on ES6 function with named arguments

Tags: node.js, eslint

I have a function defined like this:

```
const generate = (report={}, buffer=false) => {
  // do stuff
}
```

Notice how both of the parameters have default values.

When I call that function and name an argument I get a no-undef ESLint error.

```
generate(buffer = true);
```

ESLint says that "buffer" is not defined. It's not detecting that it is a named argument. Does anyone know how to change my .eslintrc to account for named arguments. I can't find anything online.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: there are no named params in js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are expecting from this code does not exists in Javascript.

You are getting no-undef ESLint error because `buffer` is never declared. Since there are no named params in JS, you could just call `generate(true)`.

Although that would actually result in `report` being equal to `true` and `buffer` being settted to its default, which you have setted to`false`.

To achieve something closer to what you are looking for, you could switch the variable orders:

`generate(buffer = false, report = {})`
And then calling `generate(true)` would cause a call having the parameters:
`buffer = true` and `report = {}`.

Hope that makes sense.

For further reading, I recommend: http://2ality.com/2011/11/keyword-parameters.html

Comment: Thanks for the reading material. You could also write it like this: `generate(undefined, true);`

Comment: Yes, you could. I'm not a big fan of using `undefined` explicitly, but I agree it would have the desired effect in this case.